# DAX subquery - translation from TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

I am trying to translate a query that I wrote in TSQL to DAX and have tough time figuring out how to use subquery in DAX. 
Here is my source SQL code:

```
Select [DayOfWeekNumber], [DayOfWeek], Ratio=Avg (100*Opened/ Sent) From
        (select [DayOfWeekNumber], [DayOfWeek], e.Schedule_ID
                , Count (e.opened) as Opened
                , Sum (e.NoOfEmailSent) as Sent
        from 
            Events e 
            join dim_date D on d.ID_Date = e.ID_Date
        where 
            e.AccountNumber = 1
        group by d.[DayOfWeek], [DayOfWeekNumber], e.Schedule_ID
        having 
            Sum (e.NoOfEmailSent) > Count (e.opened)
        ) OBSHour
group by [DayOfWeekNumber], [DayOfWeek]
Order by [DayOfWeekNumber]
```

The purpose of this query is to calculate open ratio of number of opened emails vs number of emails sent by first calculating opened / Sent for each email schedule and weekdays and then taking average of all ratios for the same weekday.
For example if data is like this for a Sunday:

```
Schedule_ID   Open Sent Ratio
123             10  100  .1
125             2    10  .2
129             1     4  .25
```

Then final ratio for Sunday will become (.1+.2+.25)/3=.18

I appreciate your help.

Comment: So explicitly *not* a weighted average?

Comment: Like if all 4 of your emails were opened on 129, your average would be 43% even though users only opened 14% of your sent emails?